# VBA copy paste - stopping at blanks - Issues with range

Tags: excel, copy-paste

Not strong in VBA but have set this macro up to copy from a sheet (stoping at blank value) and pasting into another sheet after the last set of values, working well.

Issue is I am needing to change the copying range to this ws.Range("AF3:AQ" & LastRow).Copy

When doing so it only copies the first 3 rows then stops. I can fix the range to AF3:AQ59 but it then includes blanks which is not ideal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

```
Sub DBMeters()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow, LRow As Long
  Set ws = Sheets("DB_Sort")
  Set ws1 = Sheets("DB Input")
  LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  LRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  ws.Range("A3:L" & LastRow).Copy
  ws1.Range("A" & LRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the values of LastRow. If you step through the code select it after it was claculated. Or insert `Msgbox(LastRow)` before your copy code.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but you should fully qualify the row count. `LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Msgbox(LastRow)  returning "1"

In this case it should be copying rows 3 to 9 but it is copying 1 to 4

Comment: urdearboy - thanks I have made the change but still getting my same issue.

Comment: My guess is that what you think is a blank cell isn't truly blank.  The cell has a space of some other non-visible character in it that's causing the "End(xlUp)" pass it by.  Try doing clicking in the cell and deleting it's contents and then re-trying the function.  That will tell you if it's a problem with the data and not the code.

Comment: mmm have confirmed cells above are blank. Shifted the range around a few times. The issue is occurring when going into "double Alphabet cells"  cant work out why this would be the case though?

ws.Range("AF3:AQ" & LastRow).Copy   - will return first 3 rows AF:AQ
ws.Range("AF5:AQ" & LastRow).Copy   - will return first 5 rows AF:AQ

when going back to single alphabet cell it is not as issue.

ws.Range("A3:L" & LastRow).Copy   - will start from row 3 through and copy all data until a blank is encountered.